# Onclick value to display in another output

Tags: javascript, php, forms, echo

I'm having a problem when i click the value from dropdown. It should supposedly show me in weightage(total) automatically.

[image]
Can someone help me on how to call the value by default from the marks allocation dropdown form automatically into weightage(total).

Marks Allocation code:

```
<div class="form-row">
  <label>Marks Allocation (%):</label>
  <select name="percentage" class="form-control" oninput="this.className = ''">
    <?php 
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM continous_assess"); 
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    { ?>

    <option value="">
      <?php echo $row['percentage']; ?>
    </option>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

Weightage code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Weightage</label>
  <input type="number" name="first" class="prc" />
  <input type="number" name="second" class="prc" />
  <input type="number" name="third" class="prc" />
  <input type="number" name="fourth" class="prc" />
  <input type="number" name="fifth" class="prc" />
  <label>Total</label>
  <output value="<?php echo $row['percentage'];?>"></output>
</div>
```

Comment: Start off by adding JavaScript which listens for the `change` event on the select element to get the value of the selected option. Then set that value to the `value` property of the output element. Try it out and show us your progress. This way we can help you way better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you on your way;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateVal() {
    // Get value
    var val = document.getElementById("percentage").value;

    // Set value
    document.getElementById("exampleInput").value = val;    
}
</script>

<select name="percentage" id="percentage" onchange="updateVal()">
    <option value="">- Select something -</option>
    <option value="example1">Example 1</option>
    <option value="example2">Example 2</option>
    <option value="example3">Example 3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="exampleInput" id="exampleInput">
```

Comment: if i follow this code, yes it is working but i have used echo for the select element and therefore the dropdown still appear but doesn't display the value in exampleInput field.

Comment: You probably didnt update your options value? `<option value="<?php echo $row['percentage']; ?>"><?php echo $row['percentage']; ?></option>`

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helped you out, please mark my answer as accepted by pressing the check mark